# What are characters which can be 'safely' x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: javascript

I have a library where I use javascript to insert some null value (ASCII value 0) characters in a hidden input field. They are treated as delimiters there, but the purpose is not important for this question. Till now I have seen no problem, and I can read those values on server-side.

However, one of my users have raised a red flag regarding that and I have no reference or confidence to prove otherwise. Is there any list of characters which are guaranteed that they will always get encoded properly by the browser when using x-www-form-urlencoding?

Comment: Interesting question that I can't answer with 100% certainty.